# Magento Enterprise Catalog Price Rules (rule based on custom attribute)

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, shopping-cart-price-rules, price-rules

We would like to give a discount on a product in the cart, IF the customer has exceeded a specific quantity of that product in the cart.  The complex part is, the specific quantity is custom per product - and set in a custom attribute.

Example:

1. widget custom field for sale-threshold is 5 units
2. If a customer has 4 widgets in cart, no discount is given
3. If the customer has 5 or more in the cart, then they get a discount configured in the rule

(I tried using the code for the custom attribute in the rule itself "if quantity in cart equals or is greater than sale_threshold" - but that didn't work)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure a custom attribute to be usable in cart price rules.

In BO you can do it in Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > [find and select your custom attribute].
In the "Properties" menu, set "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to "Yes"

You can also do it in a setup script :

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer->updateAttribute(
    'catalog_product',
    'custom_attribute_code',
    'is_used_for_promo_rules', 
    1
);
```